# $Y=\{0\}$ if $X/Y$ contains an isomorphic copy of $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y\subset X$ be a closed subspace. Does it follow that $Y=\{0\}$ if $X/Y$ contains an isomorphic copy of $X$?

This claim seems at first glance like it should be true and its proof even could be a homework problem. However, it would imply on the other hand that every separable Banach space (isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_{1}$) that contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell_{1}$ is isomorphic to $\ell_{1}$. Surely this cannot be true.

I have in addition not been able to prove this claim despite playing around with it for a little while (attempted a proof by contradiction) and, while not as compelling as the above reasoning, it also makes me think that this claim is false.

I would be very grateful if someone could either (1) give an example of a separable Banach space that contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell_{1}$ but is not itself isomorphic to $\ell_{1}$ or (2) suggest a hint at how to prove that the given claim is true.

Comment: $\ell^p$ has a subspace $E$ isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^p$, for which $\ell^p/E$ is also isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^p$. For another example to (1) $C([0,1])$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1$.  Generally, a Banach space $X$ contains no copy of $\ell^1$ iff every bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think to use Rosenthal's $\ell_{1}$ theorem. And that is another good example for (1). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for (1) of your question, $L_1[0,1]$ contains a copy of $\ell_1$ but they are not isomorphic
- for (2) of your question, it is not true. $\ell_p /\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\ell_p$

Comment: Great - thank you!